# C - Linked list implementation of Stack, having trouble with pop() function?

Tags: c, stack

My push function works fine, but when I pop the last integer entered into my stack, first the last integer changes to zero then if I pop it again it changes to some garbage integer (this is what is showing when running it in the console). I'm guessing it has to do something in pop() where I am not freeing the node correctly..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}Node;


Node* push(Node* root, int value){

    Node* temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = value;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(root == NULL){
        root = temp;
    }
    else{
        temp->next = root;
        root = temp;
    }
    return root;
}


int pop(Node* root){

    if(root == NULL){
        printf("nothing to pop, stack is already empty.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Node* temp = root;
    root = root->next;
    int returnValue = temp->data;
    free(temp);

    return returnValue;
}

int peek(Node* root){

    if(root == NULL){
        printf("Stack is currently empty.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return root->data;
}

int isEmpty(Node* root){

    if(root == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void display(Node* root){
    printf("\n");
    printf("List: ");
    while(root != NULL){
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        root = root->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}


int main(){

    Node* root = NULL;

    int data, choice;
    printf("\n\nMenu: (1)Push   (2)Pop   (3)Exit\n\n");

    while(1){
        printf("Enter choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        printf("\n");

        if(choice == 1){
            printf("Enter data to push: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            root = push(root, data);
            display(root);
        }

        if(choice == 2){
            pop(root);
            display(root);
        }

        if(choice == 3){
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Don't know where I'm going wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is totally correct, only problem is that whenever you are making a pop() request ,the values are getting changed only for the local root variable of pop() function. this won't change your actual root Node and that's why it is showing undesirable output
No big deal, it can be resolved in two ways:

1. You make your root variable/structure global so that every function can access it directly. also you don't need to pass your it in every function
2. fetch the updated value of the local root of the pop() function and assign it to your
   actual root variable. just like you did in your push operation.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: So if I decide to go with the latter solution, I cannot return the data I just popped because my function would have to have return type Node* , and return the root at the functions conclusion right?

Comment: yup, but if the returnvalue is necessary then you can go with other approaches also.
It totally depends on what is the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Just to review. A pointer like `Node* root` in `main` contains the address of the actual data.

The problem here is that you are passing a pointer to `pop` the address of the root node. Then in pop you try to assign to `root`, but inside the `pop` function, `root` is just a copy of the address of the actual data. When the function is done this copy of the address of the data is tossed away (not getting back to your `root` in `main`). And you have freed the structure that `root` in main is pointing to.

What you actually need to do here is pass in a pointer to a pointer to `pop` so that you can modify the original pointer in the scope of `main`.

It looks like this in main:

```
if(choice == 2)
    pop(&root); //& calls the function with the address of the root pointer
    display(root);
}
```

Then modify your pop function like this:

```
int pop(Node** root){ //function expects a pointer to a pointer
    if((Node*)*root == NULL){
        printf("nothing to pop, stack is already empty.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Node* temp = *root;
    *root = temp->next;
    int returnValue = temp->data;
    free(temp);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, I definitely see where I went wrong now, appreciate your help!